# Thumbnail Class in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Problem**

So, I am trying to fit 3 images in a row. Every Image has a different dimension.
So, I tried adding the thumbnail class hoping that it would make all images the same size but it only added the border but never changed the image size.

**What I want**

I want all images the same size.

**Code**

(The code is for one image since all images have the same code)

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo1423034816855245e5820ff8cdpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=2000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop="alt="Something in france!">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some images are affected differently with the thumbnail tag. That is because some images have a larger width than the height (ex: 480 x 670). 
[Example](http://codepen.io/amrojjeh/pen/VmWGpZ)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Image Gallery.css">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1423034816855-245e5820ff8c?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=2000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="Something in france!">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441790844170-ec5dc89c7eae?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="A sad monkey">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464039397811-476f652a343b?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1003&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="A forest!">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: codepen.io link expiered, could You update it please?

Answer (score 0):

you could do it something like this, apply `width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` to img

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27359/) for working demo

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;  // adjust it based on your need
}

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Not working, Images still don't have the same size for some reason.

Comment: http://codepen.io/amrojjeh/pen/VmWGpZ That is the whole website. Note: I realized that the forest picture got shrunken down but the thing that I forgot the name of did not.